# Xerces-C increasing memory usage

Tags: c++, memory-management, xerces-c

I'm currently struggling with rising memory usage in Xerces-C.

I was able to simplify the code to this point:

```
xercesc_3_2::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();

xercesc_3_2::DOMImplementation* impl = xercesc_3_2::DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation((const XMLCh*)L"LS");
xercesc_3_2::DOMDocument* doc = impl->createDocument();

while (true)
{
    xercesc_3_2::DOMElement* el = doc->createElement((const XMLCh*)L"root");
    el->release();
}
```

When I execute this code, the memory usage will rise up to 4 GB in ~30 seconds.

- **Do I have to call anything else than `release()` on the `DOMElement` in order to free the memory?**
- **Is there any way to truly free the memory used by a `DOMElement` without releasing the `DOMDocument`**

---

Some remarks to my questions:

- I can't destroy the `DOMDocument`. (Unfortunately I have to keep it around with a lot of `DOMElement`s being created and released)
- I know this is technically not a memory leak since the memory will free when i release the `DOMDocument`, but is this a known issue?
- I've tested the xerces-c versions `3.1.1`, `3.1.4`. `3.2.2`. The problem exists in all those versions.

Comment: Why are you deleting elements you've created? What stops you from doing the "do I actually want to create this element" logic before you create the element?

Comment: But if you've actually added the elements to the document but the document isn't complete, you wouldn't be able to free those elements in any case.

Comment: @Sneftel I think we're moving off-topic here.

Comment: Well, that depends on whether confirming that there's a bug in Xerces (sounds like there is!) will be enough to solve your problem. I suspect that it won't be.

Comment: @Sneftel I'll do my best to explain our situation: Our users are creating XML trees with our tool. at some point they can 'save' the trees by importing them into a new `DOMDocument` and wiriting the XML to a file. After importing the trees into the new Documents (xerces actually clones the old trees) we want to delete (release) the old trees, which kind of leaks memory.

Comment: Ah. It sounds like you're using Xerxes as a generalized DOM rather than just an XML reading/writing tool. That's not the worst idea, but as you've seen, it's somewhat swimming against the current as far as Xerxes is concerned. Personally I'd suggest a custom, domain-specific data model/representation and a more streamy serialization to XML. DOM-based libraries make more sense for reading than writing anyway.